# issue in removing radio buttons using javascript in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have a implementation where I am creating radio buttons dynamically, actually all the fields and values are dependent on each other like parent- child -grand child and so on. I am able to remove button but in Firefox using `innerHtml` but in IE it didn't worked. For IE, I got a diffrent code but that also doesn't worked properly below I am pasting code that generates it and removes it.

```
var idToUpdate = "radioID";
var nameToUpdate = "radioName";
var labelToUpdate = "labelText";

var tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
var row = document.createElement("tr")
var data1 = document.createElement("td")
var newRadio = document.createElement("input");
newRadio.type = "radio";
newRadio.id = idToUpdate;
newRadio.name = nameToUpdate;
newRadio.value = labelToUpdate;
if (defUpdater == 1)
    newRadio.setAttribute('checked', 'checked');
newRadio.setAttribute("onclick", "javascript:dependentFieldsValue('" + idToUpdate + "');");
var data11 = document.createElement("td")
var newLabel = document.createElement("label");
newLabel.htmlFor = idToUpdate;
newLabel.id = idToUpdate;
newLabel.appendChild(document.createTextNode(labelToUpdate));
tbody.appendChild(row);
row.appendChild(data1);
data1.appendChild(newRadio);
row.appendChild(data11);
data11.appendChild(newLabel);
Node1.appendChild(row);
defUpdater = 0;
```

For loop in last is used for removing radio, we just get htmlelemnt using table ID and set the innerHTML to="".

```
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  var node = documnet.getElemtsById("tableID"); // every button group have table and table is havin id.
  Node.childNodes[i].innerHTML = ""; /// works for firefox// works fine
  //Node.childNodes[i].Node.removeChild(Node.childNodes[i]);// works for IE but not properly
}
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Don't use markup to format your code, instead, select it and click the `{}` icon. Seems like you have 2 typos in `var node = documnet.getElemtsById("tableID");`, also (not sure if this is the case but) `table`, `thead`, `tbody` and `tr` elements' `innerHTML` property are read-only in IE.

Comment: Full-bold code now, ok. My eyes are bleeding, I'm done for the night.

Comment: your code is full with typos: documnet should be document, node and Node is not the same; javascipt is case sensitive. tbh, it's a mess.

Comment: If OP ever got that code to work, then obviously he didn't copypasta it here properly. And when/if he does post the original code, I'd be expecting another wall of bold text instead of a code block. Please select your code and use the corresponding `{}` code icon in the edit menu or type the `<pre></pre>` tags for code block instead of using standard markup next time, I'll have enough nightmares already.

Comment: Hmmm   yes..... Hi Fabricio, thanks for your reply. What i need to do in this case to resolve the issue? please suggest.. Hmm @: Fabrício Matté , i just made it bold to make it clearer :) , will tk care in future..........

Comment: your code is full with typos: documnet should be document, node and Node is not the same; javascipt is case sensitive. tbh, it's a mess. – Tom 19 mins ago.. @:Tom , thanks yes i know , this is not the problem actually.. because in my code i used Node  and document. Problem is in last four line that is for loop , which is used for removing Buttons but is not working in IE.

Answer (score 0):

I would use this construction:

```
var table = documnet.getElemtsById("tableID");
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) { 
    var tr = table.childNodes[i];
    tr.parentNode.removeChild(tr);
}
```

Comment: Thanks vaclav, but still issue is with IE, when you say tr.ParentNode.removeChild(tr) you mean- tr.table.removeChild(tr)?

Comment: Thanks vaclav, but still issue is with IE, when you say tr.ParentNode.removeChild(tr) you mean- tr.table.removeChild(tr)? can somone please let me know the way of applying css to dynamically generated code. i tried newRadio.class="css class". i need to maintain gap between buttons.

Comment: ECMAscript is case sensitive, so `ParentNode` is not equals to `parentNode`. Yes, by `tr.parentNode.removeChild(tr)` I mean `table.removeChild(tr)`. When I want just remove an `ele` element from DOM, I use `ele.parentNode.removeChild(ele)` so I don't need to find its parent, just the element itself.